# change the command ids handler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I need to change the command id's handler . For example ResetPerspectiveHandler's command id is org.eclipse.ui.window.ResetPerspective. So when we give the command is org.eclipse.ui.window.ResetPerspective it will call the ResetPerspectiveHandler. Now I wanted to restrict not to call the ResetPerspectiveHandler instead it should call my own Handlers when I give the org.eclipse.ui.window.ResetPerspective. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override an existing command handler.

You can use an `IExecutionListener` to listen for a command being executed using the `ICommandService`. The listener is informed before and after the command is executed.

```java
ICommandService commandService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getAdapter(ICommandService.class);

commandService.addExecutionListener(listener);
```

You can also listen to a specific command using:

```java
Command command = commandService.getCommand("command id");

command.addExecutionListener(listener);
```